# Multiple <app-location> elements in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Whenever you subroute with `<app-route>`, do you need more than one `<app-location>` (e.g., in the parent and the children pages)? Or is there only ever one `<app-location>` per application?

Comment: I'm currently working on something similar, but having multiple `app-location` elements causes them to conflict unless I'm just doing it wrong. Would love to hear if you gained insight into this for how to get that working

Comment: As far as my question is concerned, you do not "need" more than one. Since the `<app-route>` path is sent to any embedded children, the singular `<app-location>` suffices. I was able to get my application working with only one location element.

Answer (score 0):

App-route element have **tail** param. It contains part of url that does not match the **pattern**.

You can apply **tail** of first app-route as a **route** of second and so forth.

In my application i have a url like **/ax_admin/object/6/grid/5**.
So i need total of 4 app-routes:

```
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/ax_admin/:view" data="{{view_route_data}}" tail="{{view_tail}}">
<app-route route="{{view_tail}}" pattern="/:id" data="{{id_route_data}}" tail="{{id_tail}}">
<app-route route="{{id_tail}}" pattern="/:subview" data="{{subview_route_data}}" tail="{{subview_tail}}">
<app-route route="{{subview_tail}}" pattern="/:subid" data="{{subid_route_data}}" tail="{{subid_tail}}">
```

Then i use custom observer to detect url changes:

```
is: "ax-admin",
observers: [
    '_routeChanged(route.*)'
],
_routeChanged: function(route){    
    if(this.view_route_data && route.path == "route"){
        this.page = this.view_route_data.view;

        if(this.view_tail && this.view_tail.path){
            this.object_id = this.id_route_data.id*1 ;

            if(this.id_tail && this.id_tail.path){
                this.subpage = this.subview_route_data.subview;

                if(this.subview_tail && this.subview_tail.path)
                        this.view_id = this.subid_route_data.subid*1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```